# JS, use current screen instead of window.open because of blocking pop up

Tags: javascript, html

I am an app developer so I really don't know about web skills.

Among the APIs I am using, there is a structure in which a response comes in a pop-up window when a form submits.

```
function fnPopup(){
    window.open('', 'popupChk', 'width=500, height=550, top=100, left=100, fullscreen=no, menubar=no, status=no, toolbar=no, titlebar=yes, location=no, scrollbar=no');
    document.form_chk.action = "www.abc.net";
    document.form_chk.target = "popupChk";
    document.form_chk.submit();
}

<form name="form_chk" method="post>
    <input type="hidden" name="m" value="someValue1">               
    <input type="hidden" name="k" value="someValue2">
    <a href="javascript:fnPopup();"> Submit Click</a>
</form>
```

They seem to have used this method because this API has a structure that the session cannot be disconnected.

However, the pop up blocker is unconditionally default whether it is Chrome or Safari. I want to intercept this popup window information and display it in full screen for iOS app release. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do this:

```
<body>
<h1>My Awesome Site!</h1>
</body>
<script>
    // Create a link
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    // Link to a website
    link.href = "https://www.youtube.com/";
    // Append it to the site
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    // Click the link
    link.click();
</script>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).